# How to programmatically register "tel" protocol to an application

Tags: c#, tel

I've been driving myself nuts trying to figure this one out.
I need to **programmatically** associate the tel protocol with an application on Win 8/ Win 10. Please for those that are going to suggest the Win 7 way of editing the registery.. it doesnt work and has been noted as that. I cannot even get it to register the protocol manually. here are some references I tried:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrmlcgn/2013/02/26/windows-8-associate-a-file-type-or-protocol-with-a-specific-app-using-gpo-e-gdefault-mail-client-for-mailto-protocol/

https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/21303-how-do-you-set-protocol-association-standalone-exe.html

As a last resort I'm going to try : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/45b771f3-8b83-43d8-8133-3b5eb6f71a79/setting-default-programprotocol-associations-without-windows-store?forum=w8itproappcompat by creating  a COM app with ProgId..

But does anyone know if that will work?

I need it to open a windows forms app.

Comment: Do you crate an UWP app? If not, pls add this fact to your question.

Comment: Are there advantages (or will it make my life simpler) if it is a UWP app?

Comment: On the contrary, it will make you life harder (as far as I know, it's impossible for UWP apps until the user will choose the app for tel: manually).